# Android : Hide relativelayout when scroll down on listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, onscrolllistener

I try to add a relativelayout when the user begin to scroll down in a listview.
I would like to show the relativelayout again when the user scroll to top and when first item of the listview is displayed.

My code works but there is a little "climb" when the user try to scroll.
I think that the problem is located on listAtTop function but i don't know where.

[image]

```
list.setOnDetectScrollListener(new OnDetectScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUpScrolling() {
                    /* do something */
                    Log.d("INFO", "UPPPPPPPPPPP");
                    if (listIsAtTop()) {
                        RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
                        relative1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDownScrolling() {
                    /* do something */
                    Log.d("INFO", "DOWNNNNNNNN");
                    if (!listIsAtTop()) {
                        RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
                        relative1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });


private boolean listIsAtTop()   {   
        if (list.getChildCount() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return list.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && (list.getChildCount() == 0 || list.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
 list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }
        int mPosition=0;
        int mOffset=0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int position = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
               View v = list.getChildAt(0);
                int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

                if (mPosition < position || (mPosition == position && mOffset < offset)){
                     // Scrolled up 
                     //search_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                     // Scrolled down
                     //search_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
        }
    });
```

In this code when you scroll `down` hide layout and when you scroll up and reached to `top` then Visible layout

Comment: Thanks, but your code seems doesn't work. I never go in onScrollStateChanged function..

Comment: @wawanopoulos check it carefully becoz it's working fine in my case.

Comment: Ok, i will check again

Comment: I don't understand why i never go in onScrollStateChanged and onScroll function. Is there any code to add ?